# Como converter uma tupla para um vetor de ponteiros `void`?

Tags: c++

Tenho tuplas com objetos que podem ter diferentes tipos. Como eu faria para generalizar o código a seguir:

```
#include <iostream>

std::vector<void *> to_vector(std::tuple<int, double, std::string> x)
{
    std::vector<void *> out;
    out.push_back((void *)new int(std::get<0>(x)));
    out.push_back((void *)new double(std::get<1>(x)));
    out.push_back((void *)new std::string(std::get<2>(x)));
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, double, std::string> x = {1, 2, "hi"};
    std::vector<void *> v = to_vector(x);

    for (auto i : v)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Isto é, eu gostaria de que a função `to_vector` pudesse receber qualquer tupla e retornasse um vetor de ponteiros sem precisar explicitamente escrever todos os `push_backs`. Eu imagino que isso seja possível usando `templates` e alguma variação do que foi feito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42494715/3297472), mas não consegui de forma alguma.

Comment: você ja deu uma olhada [nisso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604794/convert-stdtuple-to-stdarray-c11)? Eu não consegui testar ainda, mas talvez te ajude.

Comment: o problema é que aparentemente isso supõe que todos elementos da tuple possuem o mesmo tipo, o que não aconece no meu caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você pode usar C++17, use [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) com [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) e [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<class ... T>
std::vector<void *> to_vector(const std::tuple<T...>& x) {
    std::vector<void*> out;
    std::apply([&out](auto&&... args) {
        out.reserve(sizeof...(args));
        ([&](){
            using elem_type_no_ref = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(args)>;
            using elem_type_no_const = std::remove_const_t<elem_type_no_ref>;
            out.push_back(new elem_type_no_const(std::forward<elem_type_no_ref>(args)));
        }(), ...);
    }, x);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::string t {"test"};
    std::string t2 {"test-move"};
    std::tuple<int, double, std::string&, int, std::string&&> x = {1, 3.14, t, 9, std::move(t2)};
    std::vector<void *> v = to_vector(x);

    int i = 0;
    std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {
        ((std::cout << *(std::remove_reference_t<decltype(args)>*)v[i++] << std::endl), ...);
    }, x);
}
```

Não se esqueça de desalocar os recursos.

Comment: meu deus que coisa linda, muito obrigado por me apresentar esse mundo